# Get text from voice command from {*} on Windows Phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, voice

If `<ListenFor>` contains {*}, it seems that it is not possible to get that part of the spoken command from `OnActivated`. Am I missing something or it is like that by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can't. The workaround is to use PhraseTopic.